# Fantasy book series - three siblings in a family of undertakers, spirit magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

Here's what I remember about this fantasy book series:

1. A family all who use spirit magic
2. Three siblings; one girl, two boys
3. The younger bother and sister love each other to the point of incest
4. The family are undertakers.
5. The younger brother helps his father in this work.
6. The father trains the boys in combat but is disappointed with his younger   son.
7. In the beginning of the story we see a small girl brought to them who they are told fell and broke her neck but in preparing the young girl the younger sibling finds signs of abuse and sets her spirit free to haunt her abuser i.e her father.

These are basically all I remember about the book. If anyone knows the title and writer, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I bet you can remember more than this - you're just not asking yourself the right questions :-) Have a look through the [checklists](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) and see if anything jogs your memory. When and where did you read it? How old was it? What language was it written in? Was it set in the real world or in an imaginary one?